# javascript variables in for each

Tags: javascript, foreach

The following code produces the following output.
But is it possible to keep the value "8888" for "index"?
In other words, how do I make the for-each variable a local one?
CODE:

```
var index = 8888;
console.log(index);
for ( index in a) { // by the way a.length = 5 
    console.log(index);
}

console.log(index);
```

OUTPUT:

```
8888
0
1
2
3
4
4
```

Comment: Use a different variable! OR wrap it in a IIFE

Answer (score 8):

Just change the name of the variable.

Instead of

```
var index = 8888;
console.log(index);
for (index in a) { // by the way a.length = 5 
    console.log(index);
}

console.log(index);
```

Use

```
var index = 8888;
console.log(index);
for (i in a) { // by the way a.length = 5 
    console.log(i);
}

console.log(index);
```

When you write `for (index in a)` you create a local variable index, that overides temporarily the other variable `index`. You can change the name of the local variable for anything different than `index`, then you won't have this problem!.

Comment: SImplest solution is to add a `let/const`. It's probably worth mentioning that you shouldn't be using a `for in` loop to iterate over arrays. Consider editing your example where you are creating a global `i`

Answer (score 4):

Scope it with `const` or `let`:

```js
var index = 8888; // `index` is 8888 here.

for(const index in a){ // `index` is "0", then "1", "2", "3", and "4" here.
  a[index];
}

// `index` is 8888 here again.
```

`const` and `let` make variables scoped to the block they are declared in: in this case a new `index` variable is scoped to each iteration of the `for` loop.
All of them overshadow the outside `index`.
After the loop ends the `index` variable declared with `var` becomes accessible again.

Comment: `let` is specific to the ES6 standard.

Comment: You might want to explain how to use this in current browsers.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I forgot to mention that… I use too much ES6 stuff myself lately, although I’ve never really used `let`… @FelixKling I’d just suggest one of the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

Scoping in Javascript is somewhat strange in that variables declared in an new scope will **not** shadow variables previously declared in a previous scope.  Your question demonstrates the textbook example of what that means.

The most compatible way to do this is to just rename your variable in your for loop:

```
var index = 8888;
console.log(index);
for (i in a) { // by the way a.length = 5 
    console.log(i);
}
```

The next most [compatible way](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/) is to use the forEach function:

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
array.forEach(function (current, arrayIndex) { 
  console.log(arrayIndex); 
});
```

The ECMA6 way that is [officially approved](http://sdtimes.com/ecmascript-6-is-officially-a-standard/) but may [still not be fully implemented by browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) is to use the [`let`  keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let).

```
var index = 8888;
console.log(index);
for ( let index in a) { // by the way a.length = 5 
    console.log(a[index]);
}

console.log(index); // still 8888
```

From the documentation:

> let vs var
>
> When used inside a block, let limits the variable's scope to that block. Note the difference between var whose scope is inside the function where it is declared

It continues:

> You can use the let keyword to bind variables locally in the scope of loops instead of using a global variable (defined using var) for that.

`let` is pretty much Javascript trying to make there scoping less crazy in a backwards compatible way.

Comment: @shmuli correct, my link shows exactly what browsers support that.

Answer (score 1):

if is mandatory to use same name, you should use self-executing anonymous JavaScript functions

```
var index = 8888; 
var a =[1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(index);
(function(){
  for (var index in a) { // by the way a.length = 5
    console.log(index);
  }
}());
console.log(index);
```

Comment: although I think it is better to rename the variable ..... @"Rafael Cardoso" solution

Answer (score 1):

See this documentation on foreach: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

You can have something like this and avoid using your own index variable (the arrayIndex variable below is local to the callback function in the forEach):

```
var array = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
array.forEach(function (current, arrayIndex) { 
  console.log(arrayIndex); 
});
```